# How can I get the text from a select box with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<select id="SubjectID"><option value='00'>Select Subject</option>
<option value=01 selected='selected'>Software</option>

<option value=02>Psychology</option>
<option value=03>Database</option>
</select>
```

I use $('#SubjectID').val() to get the value such as "01".

How can I get the text of the selected option with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the selected option with the [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) pseudo-selector (how many times can you use the word "select" in one sentence?!), and use the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the text:

```
var selectedText = $("#SubjectID option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#SubjectID option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#SubjectID option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery("#SubjectID option:selected").text();

for more information

http://api.jquery.com/select/